# Remix Ethereum IDE Deployed contract - Transfer buttons unfamiliar

Tags: remix

I have deployed my safemath contract successfully, but rather than having the usual buttons to transfer and check balances, I see Safeadd, safemul, safe Div, etc ( see image with black bkground) its different from the usual- How can I use them to transfer my tokens to wallet addresses. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

[SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.2/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) is a helper contract for deprecated Solidity versions lower than 0.8, throwing an exception in case integer overflow/underflow should happen.

You most likely wanted to deploy a different contract that uses SameMath as a helper.

In Remix IDE, you can select the desired contract to deploy in the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab, under the "Contract" selectbox.

[image]